# How to use Jest to test my API write in Node.js(express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

This is my API comments.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const users = require("../../private/users.json");
const users_info =  require('../../private/users-info.json')

router.get('/users/:user_name/comments',(req,res) => {
    if(req.params.user_name in users){
        res.send({
            content: users_info[req.params.user_name].comments,
            get_comments: true
        })
    }
    else{
        res.status(400).send({
            user: 'not exist',
            get_comments: false
        })
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

I try to write a test file app.test.js

```
const request = require('supertest');
const users_comments = require('./routes/users/comments')

describe('Test the users service', () => {
    test('GET /users/:user_name/comments succeeds',() => {
        return request(users_comments)
            //'lexun' is the username stored in users.json
        .get('/users/lexun/comments')
        .expect(200)
    });
}
```

However, it throws an error[image]

I don't know the reason that cause this error. Maybe the way I write the code for testing is wrong.
I wonder how to fix the problem or what is the right way to test my API.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your repo? Or at least show what is on the "./routes/users/comments" file? It's hard to determine the issue without seeing the other file